# How do I map my toggle buttons to their respective variables?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a collection of 12 images that I want to display on the screen as the user presses its respective toggle button.

For simplicity, I'll say that I have 3 images:

```
img.Image image1 = img.decodeImage(_imageFile.readAsBytesSync());
img.Image image2 = img.decodeImage(_imageFile2.readAsBytesSync());
img.Image image3 = img.decodeImage(_imageFile3.readAsBytesSync());

List<bool> isSelected = [true, false, false];

//only showing relevant portion of @build function
ToggleButtons(
                color: Colors.teal,
                selectedColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.accessibility),
                  Icon(Icons.pets),
                  Icon(Icons.phone),
                ],
                isSelected: isSelected,
                onPressed: (index){
                  setState(() {
                    isSelected[index] = !isSelected[index];
                    print(isSelected);
                  });
                },
              ),
```

Based on what buttons the user presses I want to display that image. I dont want to write if-else statements for all possible combinations of the `isSelected`, and based on the `isSelected` list I would display the image, for example in its default state of `[true, false, false]` only `image1` should be displayed.

How would I get all possible combinations of `isSelected`? For this purpose I found the trotter library: https://pub.dev/packages/trotter, but apparently it does not accept list of bool.

After I am able to get all possible combinations of my list that how do I map, each image to its respective toggle button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `ListView.builder` here.

Store the images in an array like `List<Image> images = [image1, image2, image3,...]`.

The code will look something like the following:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: isSelected.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    // Only render the image if it is selected.
    return isSelected[index] ? images[index] : Container();
  },
);
```

It would be best if you abstract this away by making a class (since there is an isSelected and Image for every `ListImage` let's call it.

If you have any further questions, please don't hesitate to leave a comment. Thanks :)

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Will this render only one image? or all images selected? I want the user to be able to press all buttons if needed, so at any time there will be more than 1 true in ``isSelected``. Thanks :)

Comment: All images selected! If this helped please mark as correct! Thanks :)